# Install installer package on an installed system?

Tags: system-installation, package-management

I know this will be an odd question, but I was wondering if anyone knew how to install the Ubuntu Installer package in an Ubuntu installation.  To clarify, when you boot up to an Ubuntu LiveCD, it's got the installer program available so that you can install Ubuntu to a drive.  Naturally, this program is not present in the *installed* Ubuntu.  Is there, though, a way to download and install it like other packages?

Invariably, someone will ask what I'm trying to do, and the answer is that I don't really know.  I just kinda want to tinker around with the installer and look at it and play with it; no particular reason.  Curiosity, mostly.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I could see how this would be useful if you wanted to install the current OS version on multiple external drives.

Comment: Also useful if you find yourself in a situation with ONLY a bootable Ubuntu-based Live CD/USB, lacking an installer (like Boot Repair Disk), but otherwise having Synaptic/apt-get and networking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ubiquity-frontend-gtk
```

Comment: Thanks @MatthewFlaschen (& @Xuacu)!  That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Thank you! What about for LUbuntu? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Setup  (All I had on me was a bootable USB Boot Repair Disk 64bit, but it lacks an installer)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to tinker with the installer, please do so within the confines of a running live CD, preferably using a virtual machine like KVM.  With some very small exceptions, ubiquity is written in Python, so you can install your favorite editor and modify it in place.

Equally, if you're aiming to make large changes, you can get the latest copy from revision control by running `bzr branch lp:ubiquity`.  You can build a set of Debian packages using `debuild`, then copy them to and install them in the live environment.  Alternatively, you can NFS mount the portion of the ubiquity tree that you're working on in the live environment over top of the existing directory, edit files in the branch on your local machine, then immediately test them by running the installer.

The latter approach is a stripped down version of what I use while working on it, and I find it speeds up my development, prevents me from losing changes if the virtual machine goes down, and prevents my changes from becoming out of sync with changes to the branch.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean Ubiquity? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity